# Json Array with Flask-Restless for Datatables.net

Tags: arrays, json, serialization, datatables, flask-restful

I want to use Datatables.net and it requires and json array like the below

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "9",
      "1",
      "sala",
      "zeus",
      "lights",
      "3",
      "7",
      "tcp",
    ]
}
```

But On Flask-Restfull, the nearest I could get from this is

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "channel": 9, 
      "id": 1, 
      "location": "sala", 
      "name": "zeus", 
      "purpose": "lights", 
      "role_id": 3, 
      "role_permissions": 7, 
      "type": "tcp"
    }
}
```

with this set-up:

```
manager.create_api(Device,
                   results_per_page=1000,
                   primary_key='id',
                   exclude_columns=['user_devices','role','num_results'],
                   app=app,
                   # exclude_columns=['role_id'],
                   preprocessors=dict(GET_SINGLE=[auth_func],
                                      GET_MANY=[auth_func]),
                   postprocessors={
                       'GET_MANY': [api_post_get_many]
                   }
)


def api_post_get_many(result=None, **kw):
    for key in result.keys():
        if key != 'objects':
            del result[key]
```

and this model:

```
class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'devices'

    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('id', 'name', 'purpose', 'channel', 'type','location'),
                      db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
                                        ['role_id', 'role_permissions'],
                                        ['roles.id', 'roles.permissions']
                            )
                      )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    purpose = db.Column( db.String(64))
    type = db.Column( db.String(64))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))

    channel = db.Column( db.Integer)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    role_permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)
    role = db.relationship('Role', backref=db.backref('devices'))
```

Is there a way to make FlaskRESTLESS return a json array instead of a json object? Or should I try to serialize the data with python??

Comment: Datatables can take an array of objects as well as a simple array and you can override it's requirements for the data to be stored in an array called `data` by using `"dataSrc": "objects"` within the `ajax` object.

Comment: I will give this a go. Meanwhile you can post this as answer, if it works I will accept

Comment: I'd prefer to see if it works first ;-) Thanks though. Let me know how you get on.